# Chained equality comparisons in C#

Tags: c#

I came across the following (incredibly obtuse) code today:

```
if (str == null == false)
```

My initial assumption is that it is logically equivalent to

```
if((str == null) == false)
```

and therefore

```
if(str != null)
```

Is it that simple?

Comment: we should have a competition - whats the most obscure c# way of saying if x == null

Comment: @pm100: How about: `if (((Func<bool>)(() => { bool n = false;  try { x.GetType(); } catch (NullReferenceException) { n = !n; } return n; }))())` ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. [The C# spec has left to right associativity on operators at the same precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx).

In [C# 5.0](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/B/D/0BDA894F-2CCD-4C2C-B5A7-4EB1171962E5/CSharp%20Language%20Specification.docx), the current most recent revision, you'll find it at section 7.3.1 Operator precedence and associativity.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you are correct. You just need to follow the [Operator precedence rules of C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx), which you did do in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct. It's a test if `str` is not null. And the original code is a poor, cryptic way of expressing that.

Comment: And, BTW, I find a person to be very gutless to downvote an answer without going on the record as saying what was wrong with it.

Comment: I hate when downvoters don't take the time. There should be a higher penalty when downvoting with no comment. Have an upvote.

Comment: The odd thing is we did not all get the same number of downvotes (but we all did get votes)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Yes, that seems strange to me. Almost makes me wonder if the OP was downvoting answers he didn't like. Although I see even the question got downvotes. :)

Comment: @JonathanWood For the record, I don't down vote without leaving a comment. I almost never down vote answers on my own question, because I'm always grateful for those who take the time to read and attempt to help. All of these answers at least answer the question, though some better than others.